# IV combined with matching

Tags: regression, instrumental-variable, matching

I have seen a couple of papers combining DiD with matching. Is there also something similar for IV? Especially given the problems with linear inclusion of covariates in 2SLS, [see Blandhol et al. (2022)](https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w29709/w29709.pdf)